# Find the Monthly Recurring Revenue in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I try to calculate the Monthly Recurring Revenue in a SQL Server database for subscription orders.

Getting some details from [Baremetrics about MRR](https://baremetrics.help/docs/mrr)

*How is it calculated?*

Say you have 10 customers each paying you $10 a month. Here's how you would calculate MRR.

All non-monthly plans are normalized to monthly. So if a customer is paying you $120 on an annual plan, we add $10 to MRR for the next 12 months. Neat!

So, what I have done until now, is to take care of all the raw data and include upgrades, downgrades, refunds and cancelations that could affect the MRR metric and prepare the following table:

```
DateCreated OrderID     Price   Months
2013-03-05  1           49.9500 12
2013-04-01  2           5.9500  1
2013-04-08  3           7.1100  12
2013-05-15  4           42.9500 3
2013-06-12  5           13.9850 6
2013-06-27  6           7.1100  6
2013-07-29  7           21.9250 3
```

For the MRR now. I expect to have two columns, first with the date of starting month and year (01-03-2013 for example) and the second with the total revenue based on MRR definition.

For example, the `OrderID` 1 should be divided by 12 and add the result to the current and next 11 months. `OrderID` 2 should be all on that month since the subscription plan is for 1 month and go on.

Any idea how I can proceed with the rest of it?

**Example result:**

```
Month       MRR
01-03-2013  4.1625
01-04-2013  4.1625 + 5.95 + 0.5925
01-05-2013  4.1625 + 0.5925 + 14.31 
01-06-2013  4.1625 + 0.5925 + 14.31 + 2.33 + 1.185
01-07-2013  4.1625 + 0.5925 + 14.31 + 2.33 + 1.185
01-08-2013  4.1625 + 0.5925 + 2.33 + 1.185 + 7.30
01-09-2013  4.1625 + 0.5925 + 2.33 + 1.185 + 7.30
01-10-2013  4.1625 + 0.5925 + 2.33 + 1.185 + 7.30
01-11-2013  4.1625 + 0.5925 + 2.33 + 1.185
01-12-2013  4.1625 + 0.5925
01-01-2014  4.1625 + 0.5925
01-02-2014  4.1625 + 0.5925
01-03-2014  0.5925
```

Prices to add per month:

```
49.95/12 = 4.1625
5.95/1 = 5.95
7.11/12 = 0.5925
42.95/3 = 14.31
13.985/6 = 2.33
7.11/6 = 1.185
21.925/3 = 7.30
```

I left the operations in the MRR column on the result, to make it clear. Obviously, the result should be the sum of them.

Create the input table:

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
    DateCreated datetime,
    OrderID int,
    Price float,
    Months int
);

INSERT INTO orders 
VALUES (2013-03-05, 1, 49.9500, 12),
       (2013-04-01, 2, 5.9500, 1),
       (2013-04-08, 3, 7.1100, 12),
       (2013-05-15, 4, 42.9500, 3),
       (2013-06-12, 5, 13.9850, 6),
       (2013-06-27, 6, 7.1100, 6),
       (2013-07-29, 7, 21.92500, 3)
```

Comment: you say for orderId 1 you want 49.50 / 12 = 4.125 - is that right so far?  'and add the result to the current and next 11 months.' - what would that equal?  It goes vague at that point.  Proceed by giving us a fuller example, with explanations.

Comment: Can you provide expected output for this input?

Comment: Just added an example. Please, let me know if you need more details

Comment: can you provide input table as text?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy Did you mean the queries to create the table? If yes, check the edit

Comment: Still not understanding how you are getting date ranges only from 01-03-2013 to 01-03-2014, How these date ranges generated?

Comment: Let's say that we start with the first month. 01-03-2013..Then we have an order with 12 months subscription. We need to expand the price to 12 months. So, we add 11 more months after 01-03-2013 up to 01-02-2014. When we are on order 3, we have 12 months again. So, From 01-04-2013 of that order, we ended up to 01-04-2014 since we had to add part of the price for every of the 12 months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a recursive CTE to try and get the full months range you can ever need, but I adjusted to the 1st of the month
Then I joined based on whether or not the order is applicable to that month, allowing for the fact that it remains current for n-1 further months (where n is your 'Months') - i then collected all the data in JOINER (which you could also select * from to see it) then I aggregated JOINER into a month by month summation.

I adjusted all dates to the first of the month to work with

```
WITH MTHS AS (SELECT dateADD(day, -DAY(MIN(datecreated)) + 1, MIN(datecreated)) MD, (SELECT MAX(dateadd(month,o2.months, o2.datecreated)) FROM ORDERS o2) AS MXD FROM Orders 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(month,1,MD), MTHS.MXD  FROM MTHS WHERE DATEADD(month,1,MD) < MTHS.mxd),
    JOINER AS
            (
                select MD, ord.price / ord.months mlyprice from MTHS  
                                    JOIN ORDERS ord ON dateadd(day, -day(ord.datecreated) + 1, ord.datecreated) 
                                    BETWEEN 
                                            dateadd(month,1-ord.months,MTHS.md ) 
                                            AND  
                                            MTHS.md 
            )
    SELECT J.MD,SUM(mlyprice)  FROM JOINER J GROUP BY J.MD;
```

I think it looks promising

```
    CREATE TABLE orders
(
    DateCreated datetime,
    OrderID int,
    Price float,
    Months int
);

INSERT INTO orders 
VALUES ('2013-03-05', 1, 49.9500, 12),
       ('2013-04-01', 2, 5.9500, 1),
       ('2013-04-08', 3, 7.1100, 12),
       ('2013-05-15', 4, 42.9500, 3),
       ('2013-06-12', 5, 13.9850, 6),
       ('2013-06-27', 6, 7.1100, 6),
       ('2013-07-29', 7, 21.92500, 3)


    ;WITH MTHS AS (SELECT dateADD(day, -DAY(MIN(datecreated)) + 1, MIN(datecreated)) MD, (SELECT MAX(dateadd(month,o2.months, o2.datecreated)) FROM ORDERS o2) AS MXD FROM Orders 
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT DATEADD(month,1,MD), MTHS.MXD  FROM MTHS WHERE DATEADD(month,1,MD) < MTHS.mxd),
        JOINER AS
                (
                    select MD, ord.price / ord.months mlyprice from MTHS  
                                        JOIN ORDERS ord ON dateadd(day, -day(ord.datecreated) + 1, ord.datecreated) 
                                        BETWEEN 
                                                dateadd(month,1-ord.months,MTHS.md ) 
                                                AND  
                                                MTHS.md 
                )
        SELECT J.MD,SUM(mlyprice)  FROM JOINER J GROUP BY J.MD
```

Comment: It seems it works. I don't know a lot from performance, but I guess, the job has finished :) Thanks

Comment: for performance, possible make a calculated field dateadd(day, -day(ord.datecreated) + 1, ord.datecreated) and index on it